# Want to show group values on each line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS 3.0 report that is grouped by a column called "Division". However, it only shows on division per so many rows. I'd like to have the division show on each row.
Here are screenshots of my groups and the report:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a lot harder than it should be to accomplish in SSRS. There's no straight forward way to do it. The correct way is to delete your table and start over :( but that's not usually the best idea.

A workaround that would do what you want is to right-click on your **CustomerName** column and **Insert Column -> Left** and add the Division field and header manually.
Then hide the first **Division** column (set visibility to hide). Right-click on your **CustomerName** column, go to **Column Visibility** and click **Hide**.